# How to get the data out of a DataGrid (C#)

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I want to make a vocabulary trainer. For that, I created a class for a Vocabulary. One Vocabulary has three properties (the German word, the other langued word an the status if it's enabled or not). All these properties are in lists

```
    List<String> germanWords = new List<string>();
    List<String> otherWords = new List<string>();
    List<bool> enabled = new List<bool>();
    List<VocabClass> data = new List<VocabClass>();
```

All works fine but when I want to change the properties in a DataGrip I can't find a way to get the new data and save it. 
I tried it with

```
        data = dataGrip.Items;
```

But then I get the error CS0029  cannot convert "System.Collections.Generic.List" to "System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list stored in `Items` is a generic list, you would have to convert it to your kind of list.
This can be easily done by using LINQ:

```
data = dataGrip.Items.Cast<VocabClass>()
                          .Select(item => new VocabClass() { Content = item.Content})
                          .ToList();
```